# Using named URL's in an included URL config in Django

Tags: python, django

If I have a URL config for my Django website that includes the URL config for an app it uses like this:

```
urls = pattern('',
    url(r'^foo/', include(my_app.urls)),
)
```

And the app's URL config looks something like this:

```
urls = pattern('',
    url(r'^bar/', my_view, name = 'bar'),
)
```

How can I get access to bar from a template using the url tag? I get a NoReverseMatch error when I use just bar and when I've tried my_app.bar.

What I've tried:

```
{% url 'bar' %}
[% url 'my_app.bar' %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `{% url 'my_app:bar' %}` work?

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: which version of django? If pre-1.5, `{% url bar %}` should do , since you are not using namespaces

Comment: According to the following, your first tag usage should work.  Make sure you're including any required params required from the url.conf.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: I'll give those a shot quick. Thanks for the fast responses. I'm using Django 1.5 to be clear.

Comment: Yep that worked. I added the namespace and app_name to the include statement then just adjusted my templates to use 'app_name:name'. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following Mike and alecxe's advice. I changed my include statement to be

```
url(r'^foo/', include(my_app.urls, namespace = 'my_namespace', app_name = 'my_app'),
```